# Eliminar un solo dato de una tabla de un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

¡Hola! Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<main>
       <div class="main-container">
           
        <?php

        include("conexion.php");
        
        $usuario = $_GET['username'];
        if ($_SESSION['gratuito'] == $usuario || $_SESSION['exclusivo'] == $usuario || $_SESSION['admin'] == $usuario || $_SESSION['creador'] == $usuario) {

           ?>
           <a href="eliminar-notif.php?username=<?php echo "$usuario"?>">Eliminar todas las notificaciones.</a>
           <?php
    
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $titulo = $row['titulo'];
            $texto = $row['texto'];
            $tipo = $row['tipo'];
            ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$titulo" ?></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$texto" ?></p><br>
            </div>
            <?php
                if ($tipo == 1) {
                    ?>
                    <form method="post">
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="aceptar" type="submit" name="aceptar" value="ACEPTAR">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                    <input class="rechazar" type="submit" name="rechazar" value="RECHAZAR">
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                }
        }
            $leido = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE notificaciones SET leer = '1' WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
        } else {
            ?>
            <h2 class="h2-notif">¡Esta no es tu cuenta! No puedes andar investigando los mensajes de los demas, eso solo lo hacen las personas feas, y tu no eres feo... ¿No?</h2>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
       </div>
       <?php
       include("aceptar-invitacion.php");
        ?>
    </main>
```

Este es el formulario, y este es el codigo php para aceptar la invitacion:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['aceptar'])) {
    
    $query_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '$usuario'");
    
    $row_equipo = mysqli_fetch_array($query_usuario);
    $equipo = $row_equipo['equipo'];
    
    $query_aceptar = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE usuarios SET equipo='$equipo' WHERE username = '$usuario'");
} else if (isset($_POST['rechazar'])) {
    $query_eliminar = "DELETE FROM notificaciones WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND leer = '1'";
}

?>
```

la base de datos es:

- id
- tipo
- titulo
- texto
- usuario
- desde
- leer

Bueno, basicamente, quiero poner que, si un usuario presiona "Rechazar" la notificacion se elimine, pero no se como seleccionar una sola de estas notificaciones y solo se elimine la seleccionada. (Notese que cada notificacion tiene un boton de "eliminar notificacion" propia), pense en usar un link que lleve a otra pagina que haria todo el procedimiento llevandose el id del boton, pero no es esa mi idea. Sin embargo, si no hay otra manera, lo hare asi.
Creo que se entiende mi pregunta, ¿No?, basicamente, ¿Como hago para que, si presiono un input type submit de una notificacion en concreto, se elimine solo esa notificacion de la base de datos y nada mas?.
Lo mejor que logre hacer fue un select de todas las notificaciones con leer en 1 y que se eliminen, pero eso haria que se eliminen todas las notificaciones (ya que, al usuario entrar al menu de notificaciones, las habra leido ya).
Uso PHP vanilla, sin jquery, ni ajax ni nada, con estilo por procedimientos en mysql.
Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Comment: Hola, no creo que pueda hacerlo sin utilizar java script, al menos cuando presione el boton eliminar utilizar un input que este hidden y que le cambie la propiedad value y por ultimo hace el submit

Comment: Oh, esa es buena, si no funciona la respuesta que me dieron podria usarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello debes pasar el id de tu tabla a cada uno de los registros que estás mostrando.

Simplemente agregar un `<td>` a la tabla donde decidas colocar las opciones y envias en el action la ruta junto junto con el id que identifica el registro que quieras eliminar.

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<td>
  <form onSubmit=" return confirm('Email will be deleted from all lists. Are you sure?')" 
action="/delete_row/<?= $row['id'] ?>" method="POST" style="display:inline;">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" title="Delete Email">
        <i class="fas fa-trash" title="Delete Email"></i>
    </button>
  </form>
</td>
```

Ya en el archivo relacionado a la ruta post a la que envías tu formulario recibes la variable en un `$_POST['id']` y ese es el id que utilizaras en tu WHERE de SQL para eliminar.

Comment: Ok, ese codigo html de form nunca lo vi xdxd, no lo entendi, ¿Que es todo ese codigo? ¿Debo personalizarlo? soy bastante nuevo en esto.

Comment: No entendi desde "onSubmit= " return confirm('Email will be deleted from all lists. Are you sure?')" action="/delete_row/"

Comment: Ohhhh, creo que entiendo!!!, voy a probarlo, ¡Gracias!

Comment: Saludos, es solo una función predefinida de JS para validar si se está seguro que se desea eliminar un registro. Me alegra que hayas podido adaptarlo a tu código.